# Access on-the-fly generated UIElements in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Correct me if there is a better way of doing this :)

I have to add `UIElement` (in my case `StackPanel`) dynamically to my xaml.

My code:

```
foreach (Dienstleistung dienstleistung in dienstleistungenList)
{
    var xaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(StackPanelTemplate);
    var deepCopy = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as StackPanel;
    foreach (UIElement child in deepCopy.Children)
    {
        if (child is TextBlock)
        {
            var y = child as TextBlock;
            switch (y.Text)
            {
                case "Titel":
                    y.Text = dienstleistung.Title;
                    break;
                case "Beschreibung":
                    y.Text = dienstleistung.Summary;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    MainContainer.Children.Add(deepCopy);
}
```

Xaml:

```
<WrapPanel Name="MainContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Name="StackPanelTemplate" Margin="5px" Width="200px" MouseLeftButtonUp="StackPanelOnClick">
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightCyan"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <Image Margin="5px" Width="190px" Height="190px"></Image>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="5px" FontSize="16">Titel</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="5px">Beschreibung</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtNum" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="50" Text="0" TextChanged="txtNum_TextChanged" />
                <Button x:Name="cmdUp" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="5,5,0,5" Content="˄" Width="20" Click="cmdUp_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="cmdDown" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Content="˅" Width="20" Click="cmdDown_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

In short, I have a template and I copy it.

Now I have a `TextBox` in my template, where I have a `TextChanged` event. Now my question is, why does this event not fire? And is there a way of accessing those generated elements?

Comment: Throw away all your code and carefully read the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN. Then create a view model with an ObservableCollection of Dienstleistung items and bind a ListBox's ItemsSource property to that collection. In the ItemTemplate of the ListBox, declare TextBoxes and bind their Text property to the appropriate Dienstleistung property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [Serialization Limits of XamlWriter.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) Event Handling is not preserved during serialization. If you think about it for a bit, the reason for this should be obvious. Even if it was somehow able to recognize that the object attached to said event was a control it could serialize and further recognize when it had already serialized a component to avoid endless loops, what would happen when it was deserialized? You certainly wouldn't have the `TextChanged` event hooked to the exact same object that already existed... it would have to create another instance of the control that the code behind is implemented in and attach to that, because it has no way of knowing about the one already in memory.

Luckily, there is a better way to achieve what you're trying to do. In WPF when you want to repeat a control a variable number of times over a list of some sort, you want to look at using an [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) or one of its derivations. If you bind your list of items to the `ItemsSource` dependency property and then place the control you want over each item within the `ItemTemplate`, the framework will create a new instance of the `ItemTemplate` for each item in the list, set it as a child of the `ItemsControl` and set the `DataContext` of the newly created control to the item in the list it created it for. Moving your XAML around a bit, it will end up looking something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DienstleistungenList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanelTemplate"
                        Width="200px"
                        Margin="5px"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="StackPanelOnClick">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <Image Width="190px"
                       Height="190px"
                       Margin="5px" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5px"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5px"
                           Text="{Binding Summary}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtNum"
                             Width="50"
                             Margin="5,5,0,5"
                             x:FieldModifier="private"
                             Text="0"
                             TextChanged="txtNum_TextChanged" />
                    <Button x:Name="cmdUp"
                            Width="20"
                            Margin="5,5,0,5"
                            x:FieldModifier="private"
                            Click="cmdUp_Click"
                            Content="˄" />
                    <Button x:Name="cmdDown"
                            Width="20"
                            Margin="0,5,0,5"
                            x:FieldModifier="private"
                            Click="cmdDown_Click"
                            Content="˅" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As has been suggested in the comments, I would recommend reading the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) but would also add the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) as both of these are critical to understanding how to write a XAML based application.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot :D